# How is the following property resolved ${sys:foo} by Log4j2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j2

I am looking at a `log4j2.xml` configuration from Spring Boot and see the following configuration (unimportant parts removed):

```
<Property name="PID">????</Property>
<Property name="LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD">%xwEx</Property>
<Property name="LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN">%5p</Property>
<Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
    ... %clr{${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN}} %clr{${sys:PID}}{magenta}
    ... %m%n${sys:LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD}
</Property>
```

Lets take a look: `${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN}` is clear, it resolves to the property defined in the line above. But The next two variable expansions have a `sys:` prefixed, what exactly does that do?

More importantly who does the resolution of these variables (in particular `sys:`)? Is it Log4j2 specific? Is this expansion done by **Maven** or maybe the **Spring Framework** which I am using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup. In particular the Interpolator class and the SystemPropertiesLookup class.

The Interpolator will attempt to use the SystemPropertiesLookup which returns

```
return System.getProperty(key);
```

If the result is null it will then try a default lookup, which is a MapLookup.

```
if (map == null) {
            return null;
   }
   return map.get(key);
```

This map is the map defined by the properties section in the config.

**TLDR**

The lookups are handled by log4j2 core. First it will try and get the system property. if no system property exists it will then look for a property defined in the properties section of your config.